# spring security session identifier not updated

Tags: spring, security, session

We have scanned an Spring security app in lab with IBM appscan, and there is a "Session Identifier Not Updated" medium alert . Everything is default, and it is running under Tomcat. So this is a  Tomcat issue or Spring Security issue? We are kind of confused by this because it should be a popular out of box combination

Original Request:
j_username&j_password

then it was posted to: 
http://localhost/j_spring_security_checkj

Original Response
POST /sp/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Cookie: JSESSIONID=14FF774AB81BC86D988D588AC2555BE6 Accept-Language: en-US Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Referer: http://localhost/sp/ Host: localhost  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0) Content-Length: 23  j_username=&j_password=

Appscan seems complained about: 
The test result seems to indicate a vulnerability because the session identifiers in the Original Request (on the left) and in the Response (on the right) are identical. They should have been updated in the response.

Answer (score 0):

AppScan is reporting that the application may be a potential target for [Session Fixation Attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).

Spring Security documentation has a [section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#session-mgmt) dedicated to preventing this type of attacks.  You will want to try the `newSession` setting mentioned in this section to get rid of the AppScan warning.

Comment: what I do not understand, spring security has been popular for a while, how can it is still vulnerable for this attack?

Comment: It is not Spring Security but the web app that is vulnerable to the attack. Spring Security helps protect against the attack by setting `session-fixation-protection` to `newSession`.This is not done by default because Spring Security does not know how the app uses the HTTP session. You can raise a JIRA issue to request the team to consider making the setting a default.